# dimshuffle equivalent function in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I often use [`theano.tensor.dimshuffle`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.dimshuffle). Is there an equivalent function for Numpy?

I guess I could do the same via several `numpy.swapaxes` and `numpy.newaxis` (for broadcast dimensions), `numpy.reshape` but is there some simpler or more direct way, just like `dimshuffle`?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

Comment: You may want to add a python tag.

Comment: @Divakar you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `numpy.transpose` permits any permutation of the axes of an array.

The variety `array.T` is a special case of this, corresponding to `array.transpose()` without arguments, which defaults to `array.transpose(range(array.ndim)[::-1])`.

`numpy.swapaxes` is `numpy.transpose` restricted to permutations of two axes.

`theano.tensor.dimshuffle` essentially corresponds to `numpy.transpose`, but in addition, it permits the creation of new axes of length 1 for broadcasting, by adding `'x'` wherever an axis should be created. In numpy, this can be achieved using a combination of `transpose` and `reshape`.

Note that in numpy, care is taken to make `transpose` return a view on the data whenever possible. In theano this is probably the case, too, but may depend on how the code is optimized.